# FInding the SRID for NAD_1927_UTM_Zone_7N?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, united-states, srid

How do I find the SRID for this shapefile? (output from `ogrinfo -so`)

```
Geometry: Polygon
Feature Count: 3
Extent: (-76840.712074, 7832057.693703) - (123912.271665, 7979730.291856)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["NAD_1927_UTM_Zone_7N",
    GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1927",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",
            SPHEROID["Clarke_1866",6378206.4,294.9786982]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-141.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]]
```

I know the shapefile polygons are in Alaska. I can [find a zone 17N on spatialreference.org](http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/?search=NAD27&srtext=Search) but not a 7N. Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/?search=NAD27&srtext=Search has a second page ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Prj2EPSG](http://prj2epsg.org/search) website from Boundless has a useful converter for converting from WKT SRS representations to ESPG codes.

Using the information you've given it reports an exact match for [EPSG:26707](http://prj2epsg.org/epsg/26707).